# Why does bytes.length = 0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, binary, webforms

I am not sure how to debug this.  I am trying to upload a file into my database (by reading the binary file contents into my stored procedure).  I am passing the input stream to my method like so:

```
LoadFile(gAttachmentContentID, file.InputStream, trn);
```

This is my method:

```
    public static void LoadFile(Guid gAttachmentContentID, Stream stm, IDbTransaction trn)
            {
                const int BUFFER_LENGTH = 40 * 1024;
                byte[] binFILE_POINTER = new byte[32];
                //Testing check out check in
                // 01/20/2006 Paul.  Must include in transaction
                SqlProcs.spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_InitPointer(gAttachmentContentID, ref binFILE_POINTER, trn);

                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stm))
                {
                    int nFILE_OFFSET = 0;
                    byte[] binBYTES = reader.ReadBytes(BUFFER_LENGTH);
                    Debug.Print("binBYTES=" + binBYTES.Length.ToString());
                    while (binBYTES.Length > 0)
                    {
                        // 08/14/2005 Paul.  gID is used by Oracle, binFILE_POINTER is used by SQL Server. 
                        // 01/20/2006 Paul.  Must include in transaction
                        SqlProcs.spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset(gAttachmentContentID, binFILE_POINTER, nFILE_OFFSET, binBYTES, trn);
                        nFILE_OFFSET += binBYTES.Length;
                        binBYTES = reader.ReadBytes(BUFFER_LENGTH);
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Why does `binBYTES.length = 0`?  How can I debug this type of thing?**

**Edit:**

I am now using this function:

```
    public static void LoadFile2(Guid gAttachmentContentID, Stream stm, IDbTransaction trn)
    {

        stm.Position = 0;
        byte[] binFILE_POINTER = new byte[32];

        // Now read s into a byte buffer. 
        byte[] bytes = new byte[stm.Length];
        int numBytesToRead = (int)stm.Length;
        int numBytesRead = 0;
        while (numBytesToRead > 0)
        {
            // Read may return anything from 0 to 10. 
            int n = stm.Read(bytes, numBytesRead, 10);
            // The end of the file is reached. 
            if (n == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            numBytesRead += n;
            numBytesToRead -= n;



        }
        stm.Close();
        SqlProcs.spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset(gAttachmentContentID, binFILE_POINTER, 0, bytes, trn);
        // numBytesToRead should be 0 now, and numBytesRead should 
        // equal 100.
        Console.WriteLine("number of bytes read: {0:d}", numBytesRead);

    }
```

With this procedure:

```
public static void spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset(Guid gID, byte[] binFILE_POINTER, Int32 nFILE_OFFSET, byte[] byBYTES, IDbTransaction trn)
        {
            IDbConnection con = trn.Connection;
            using ( IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand() )
            {
                cmd.Transaction = trn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                if ( Sql.IsOracle(cmd) )
                    cmd.CommandText = "spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOff";
                else
                    cmd.CommandText = "spATTACHMENTS_CONTENT_WriteOffset";
                IDbDataParameter parID               = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@ID"              , gID                );
                IDbDataParameter parFILE_POINTER     = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@FILE_POINTER"    , binFILE_POINTER    );
                IDbDataParameter parMODIFIED_USER_ID = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@MODIFIED_USER_ID",  Security.USER_ID  );
                IDbDataParameter parFILE_OFFSET      = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@FILE_OFFSET"     , nFILE_OFFSET       );
                IDbDataParameter parBYTES            = Sql.AddParameter(cmd, "@BYTES"           , byBYTES            );
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

But I get the following error:

```
Invalid text, ntext, or image pointer value 0x00000000000000000000000000000000.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code and it works fine now:

IDbConnection con = trn.Connection;
            using (IDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.Transaction = trn;

```
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE ATTACHMENTS_CONTENT SET ATTACHMENT = @BYTES Where ID=@ID";

            // 2. define parameters used in command object
            SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@BYTES";
            param.Value = bytes;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

            // 2. define parameters used in command object
            SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
            param2.ParameterName = "@ID";
            param2.Value = gAttachmentContentID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

It suggests that you've reached the end of the stream already. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes.aspx):

> The end of the file that is being read is detected when the length of the Byte array returned from ReadBytes is zero.

Personally I just wouldn't create a `BinaryReader` here at all: I'd create a *single* byte array which you can reuse, and just call `Stream.Read` repeatedly (and copying the data out) until that returns 0 to indicate that it's reached the end of the stream.

Comment: Jon, could you please provide me a sample; I am a little new to reading files in C#.  Thank you.

Comment: @user1477388: I suggest you spend a while trying on your own, and edit that code into the question. You'll learn much more that way. (Look at the documentation of Stream.Read for a starting point.)

Comment: Jon, I took your advice and tried researching this on my own.  However, I am getting the error `Invalid text, ntext, or image pointer value 0x00000000000000000000000000000000.`.  I posted my whole code, do you think you might no what's wrong?

Comment: @user1477388: You're only calling your `write` method *outside* the loop, so you're losing all but the last few bytes of data. It's not clear how you're trying to write, to be honest - if you need to do it all in one go, you could copy to a `MemoryStream` first, then call `ToArray` on that at the end.

Comment: Jon, I am pretty confused.  If you could provide me with an example that would lead me in the right direction, it would be very helpful.

Comment: @user1477388: Okay, I'll try to do so later - but it won't be for several hours I'm afraid, as I'm about to give a talk...

Comment: Break a leg!  I'll try to figure it out in the mean time :)